# show events with its correct time (not the time slot) in fullcalendar timegrid (V5.5)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'd like to have the real start and end time of an event in time gried view.
Currently fc show they start end inside the current view. Means:
Wenn a event start a 14:00 - 18:00 but current view (slotMinTime/slotMaxTime) is 16:00 - 20:00 fullcalendar show in the event as time label 16:00 to 18:00 which is not correct.

[image: fullcalender1]
[image: fullcalender2]

So fullcalender cut off the time to the current view.

**Question:** Is there a fc parameter or something else to fix that easy?

If not, I will correct the times via the the `eventDidMount` hook (I use it already to insert icons) - but this is a hack, where I have to manage each view separate and for sure i will have some format problems. Therefore this is not may favorate way.

Info: This is not about events which span Multiple days.

Remark: I fetch my event Ajax and check that there the correct valuee is in:

```
    title   "Aerobic & more - Leistungstraining (TSC 2)"
    start   "2021-02-09T14:00:00+01:00"
    end "2021-02-09T18:00:00+01:00"
    backgroundColor "#00ffff"
    classNames  "mgxo_full_event"
    extendedProps   Object { vnr: "1001", vkalnr: "27", evnr: "2", … }
 ...
```

Comment: `Is there a fc parameter or something else to fix that easy`...no. By setting minTime you've specifically told fullCalendar not to display anything before that time. It isn't hidden, it simply isn't drawn at all when the calendar is rendered.

Comment: However, the start time issue looks like it might be a bug in fullCalendar. This CodePen reproduces it: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEBpxgB . You can report it by following the instructions here: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . There's nothing we can do about that on StackOverflow. We can help you with issues when implementing fullCalendar, but not with internal problems in the library.

Comment: Thanks! I'd report a bug.

Comment: Fullcalendar insists that it is a bug. Perhaps I didn't express myself well enough, as English is not my native language. See https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/6162